# How can I monitor the changes in database?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I want to monitor changes that occur in the database. Say, for instance when an item is removed from the database. I want to be able to use an interface to monitor such changes and create an alert of how many no of items are left in the database . Every 5 min or so. Is there any plugin for java, or some kind of interface or something else? I will be grateful for the help.

Comment: Pretty sure something like this should go on Software Recommendations: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Best Option Use DDL TRIGGER as it is DB change event meaning 
       `CREATE DDL TRIGGER 
       ON DB AFTER DELETE AS 
      "YOUR ACTION STATEMENT" ;`